# Sharepoint C# send Email in x Minutes

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have an application Page where the user can input a date with time. I want to send a email on this time it can be in 2 hour 2 month or years. I know how to send email in C# but i dont know how to send in 2 hours etc. The Problem is if the Page is closed/unloaded the code on it stops running. So I think I need a service or something. Is there any Object/Class that can do this? Or can I tell Sharepoint to send an Email in x minutes?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you check the available workflow steps?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to develop an own solution.

The first idea I'd have is to store the mails to be sent in a hidden list instead of sending them (with receiver, timestamp and subject+body as fields), and then use a timer job to check the list and send the mails accordingly.

Another solution would be to use workflows.

Comment: I didnt say it in the question this application page is part of a Sharepoint solution

Comment: With solution I did not mean the technical term for `SharePoint solution`. If your application page is already part of a solution under your control, you can easily add your own elements like lists and jobs to your solution.